# How to check if a date I passed

Tags: php, date

I'm getting a issue where I can't compare two dates in the format dd/mm/yyyy to check if a date is passed or not. code:

```
$Today = date('d/m/Y');
$fakturaDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $retrieved_DPFDT3);
if ($fakturaDate < $Today ) {
    $x+= $y;
}
```

I don't know if the format is the problem, but if I could use the current it you be much easier.

Comment: Try with `$Today = new DateTime;`

Comment: here `$Today` is a string! Better make `$Today` a `DateTime` also, then there should be no problem in comparing them

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is in that you are comparing string `date('d/m/Y')` with `DateTime` object.

Just use `DateTime` for both dates (-;

```
$Today = new \DateTime();
$fakturaDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $retrieved_DPFDT3);
if ($fakturaDate < $Today ) {
    $x+= $y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Compare dates using php function

`if(strtotime($fakturaDate) < strtotime($Today))`

Try searching on how to compare dates in php.